# Codeigniter. Processing output with _output function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to process the final output in CI as I understand it from the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#processing-output).

My controller:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index(){
        echo 'Hello World!!';
    }

    public function _output($output)
    {

        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            echo $output;
        }else{
            echo '<h1>Header</h1>';
            echo $output;
        }

    }


}
```

expected output:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
Hello World!!
```

what I got:

```
Hello World!!
<h1>Header</h1>
```

what happened is that the output of index() is displayed then _output() is executed with $output as empty string

Comment: It's working as hooks(`display_override`) at the final stage, this is an expected result according to the document.

Comment: thanks, I used hooks already to solve the problem

Comment: I think it's not really clear in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's badly documented I will admit. Confusing sounding even.

But you can do this:

```
public function index(){
    $this->output->set_output('Hello World!!');
}

public function _output($output)
{

    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo $output;
    }else{
        echo '<h1>Header</h1>';
        echo $output;
    }

}
```

I should note I've never seen `_output()` method utilized. If you are more clear on what you want to achieve I might be able to offer a better alternative.

---

Possible better alternative:

```
function index() {
    $data_array['some_db_result'] = $this->somemodel->get_results();
    $this->template->render('Some heading', 'view_page1', $data_array); 
}
```

Template model:

```
function render($heading, $view_page, $data) {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo "<h1>{$heading}</h1>";
        echo $this->load->view($view_page, $data, true);
    } else {
        $data['heading'] = $heading;
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view($view_page, $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was playing with it for a long time and didn't figure that out.
I want to make my website pages to load content without refreshing the page using ajax, so if the request is ajax the controller will return only the content without the header and the footer to javascript, otherwise it will return the hole page.
Thank you

Comment: I've added an alternative that I believe is more flexible in the long term